# Where is the `mpl_token_metadata.so` file?

Tags: metaplex, mpl-token-metadata

I'm trying to use Metaplex Amman to run a local solana validator that has the Token Metadata program preloaded. I need this to create a token. At least I think I do. Every example I look at, no one is using just the plain old spl library, they're the `create_metadata_accounts_v3` function from metaplex.

```
 let seeds = &["SOLvault".as_bytes(), &[ctx.bumps.vault_info]];
        let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];

        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
            CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
                metadata: ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                // Get the account info for the current program
                mint_authority: ctx.accounts.vault_info.to_account_info(),
                payer: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                update_authority: ctx.accounts.vault_info.to_account_info(),
                system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
            },
        )
        .with_signer(signer_seeds);

        let data: DataV2 = DataV2 {
            name: metadata.name,
            symbol: metadata.symbol,
            uri: metadata.uri,
            seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
            creators: None,
            collection: None,
            uses: None,
        };

        create_metadata_accounts_v3(cpi_context, data, true, true, None)?;
```

Here is my amman config file
`.ammanrc.js`

```
const LOCALHOST = "http://localhost:8899";
const WSLOCALHOST = "ws://localhost:8900/";

module.exports = {
  validator: {
    killRunningValidators: true,
    programs: [
      {
        label: "Token Metadata Program",
        programId: "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s",
        deployPath: localDeployPath("mpl_token_metadata"),
      },
    ],
    jsonRpcUrl: LOCALHOST,
    websocketUrl: WSLOCALHOST,
    commitment: "singleGossip",
    ledgerDir: ".anchor/ledger",
    resetLedger: true,
    verifyFees: false,
    detached: process.env.CI != null,
  },
  relay: {
    enabled: process.env.CI == null,
    killlRunningRelay: true,
  },
  storage: {
    enabled: process.env.CI == null,
    storageId: "mock-storage",
    clearOnStart: false,
  },
};

function localDeployPath(program) {
  switch (program) {
    case "mpl_token_metadata":
      return "/Users/jake/Github/mpl-token-metadata/programs/.bin/mpl_token_metadata.so";
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown program ${program}`);
  }
}
```

First I looked for the actual token metadata program in the `metaplex-program-library` repository, but it says that the token metadata program has been moved to its own repository. So I moved to looking at the `mpl-token-metadata` repository. I have tried building the code here following their README instructions
[image]

Here is my result

```
jake@Jakes-MacBook-Pro mpl-token-metadata % pnpm install
Lockfile is up to date, resolution step is skipped
Already up to date
Done in 312ms
jake@Jakes-MacBook-Pro mpl-token-metadata % pnpm programs:build

> @ programs:build /Users/jake/Github/mpl-token-metadata
> ./configs/program-scripts/build.sh

Dumping external programs to: './programs/.bin'
/Users/jake/Github/mpl-token-metadata/configs/program-scripts/dump.sh: line 41: sha256sum: command not found
/Users/jake/Github/mpl-token-metadata/configs/program-scripts/dump.sh: line 42: sha256sum: command not found
[ SKIPPED ] on-chain and local binaries are the same for 'mpl_token_auth_rules.so'
/Users/jake/Github/mpl-token-metadata/configs/program-scripts/dump.sh: line 41: sha256sum: command not found
/Users/jake/Github/mpl-token-metadata/configs/program-scripts/dump.sh: line 42: sha256sum: command not found
[ SKIPPED ] on-chain and local binaries are the same for 'mpl_system_extras.so'
/Users/jake/Github/mpl-token-metadata/configs/program-scripts/dump.sh: line 41: sha256sum: command not found
/Users/jake/Github/mpl-token-metadata/configs/program-scripts/dump.sh: line 42: sha256sum: command not found
[ SKIPPED ] on-chain and local binaries are the same for 'mpl_token_extras.so'
/Users/jake/Github/mpl-token-metadata/configs/program-scripts/dump.sh: line 41: sha256sum: command not found
/Users/jake/Github/mpl-token-metadata/configs/program-scripts/dump.sh: line 42: sha256sum: command not found
[ SKIPPED ] on-chain and local binaries are the same for 'rooster.so'
/Users/jake/Github/mpl-token-metadata/configs/program-scripts/dump.sh: line 41: sha256sum: command not found
/Users/jake/Github/mpl-token-metadata/configs/program-scripts/dump.sh: line 42: sha256sum: command not found
[ SKIPPED ] on-chain and local binaries are the same for 'spl_token_2022.so'

./configs/program-scripts/build.sh: line 24: jq: command not found
jake@Jakes-MacBook-Pro mpl-token-metadata %
```

It looks like maybe the build script failed? It's not completely clear. Either way, I don't see the `mpl_token_metadata.so` file that I need anywhere
[image]

The token metadata program README says the programs should be in `programs/.bin`, but there is no `mpl_token_metadata.so` file there. I'm totally lost on how to get these metaplex programs to work. I swear I'm following all of their README instructions but all of the build scripts fail and I can't find the program file I need. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Solana CLI to make a dump from the chain

```
solana program dump metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s mpl_token_metadata.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I lost sight of the forest for the trees, trying to figure this out for so long.

Thanks to chatgpt I finally figured out I needed to install some libs that I didn't have and weren't mentioned in the README.
`brew install coreutils jq`

Then I did a `rustup update` and a `cargo clean` and deleted the `cargo.lock` file in `token-metadata` crate. Finally I ran the build script again, but passing in the correct argument.
`npm run programs:build token-metadata`.

Finally I have the `token_metadata.so` file. So I also had the name wrong in the title of this post.
[image]